# OAuth2 MS and Google differences regarding public or confidential client

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, smtp-auth

I implemented OAuth2 for SMTP for two providers **Google** and **Microsoft**.

It works so far. The only difference is that if I call Microsoft, I'm not allowed/forced to submit a *client secret*. If I use Google, I'm forced to use a *client secret*.

As far as I understood, **Google** sees my application as a **confidential client**. **Microsoft** sees me as a **public client**.

Sadly, I found no way to make my Google protocol also a **public client** without using a client secret. I found no setting in the Web-GUI of google to do so. And I found no information for my URLs or scopes to call to indicate a **public client**. Except of the URLs and scopes, the implementation is identical.

What is needed to make my Google app also a **public client**?